# Comparing infinity with real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, notation

This question is more about conventional notations in mathematics. Could we compare infinity with a real number and write something like $-\infty<0$? I have not seen this notation before but at the same I was not told not to use it. I tend to think of infinity as a concept rather than a number, but I was wondering such notations are allowed in mathematics.

The motivating reason behind this question is that I was trying to show the topology generated by all sets of the form $(-\infty,a)$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ does not contain the topology generated by the finite complement topology. For instance, $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is in the finite complement topology but for the set $(0,\infty)$ it is impossible to have a basis of the form $(-\infty,a)$ because $-\infty<0$. If this notation is not allowed, how one would go about it?

Comment: Comparing infinity with real numbers is best left to the professionals.

Comment: We can say or write whatever we want.  But for it to be *true* we must define what it *means* and verify it is true.  Mathimaticians *indeed* will write $-\infty < 0$ (or $0 < \infty)$ but they do *not* mean $-\infty$ is a real number and using the euclidean order of real numbers $-infty$ is less than $0$.  What they do mean... well, I'm going to second Gerry Myerson's comment about best to leave it to the professionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to treat $\infty$ rigorously. The issue is that we have to be very careful how we do this (when we do, anyways). Here are some examples:

- Positive or negative infinity as an [*extended* real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) - this is what you're thinking about, essentially. Expressions like "$(-\infty,0)$" and even "$(42, +\infty]$" are meaningful in this system, and - as long as we avoid square brackets at infinity! - amount to taking the usual interpretation and making the notation meaningful. The extended real numbers are quite convenient in certain situations, e.g. measure theory.
- Infinity as a *single* point at infinity (so a "number *circle*," or "[number *sphere*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)," or something similar).
- Infinity as a measure of size of sets - that is, the [transfinite cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number).
- Infinity as a kind of generalized length of a process - that is, the [transfinite ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). Ordinals and cardinals each generalize the notion of *natural number*, not of *real number*. In a [precise sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Initial_ordinal_of_a_cardinal) every cardinal is an ordinal, but not conversely.
- Infinity as a "generalized real number," that is, an infinite element of a non-Archimedean ordered field (consider e.g. the [*surreal numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number)). Here for example we can subtract infinities from each other in a well-behaved way - which we can't do in any of the other approaches above.

Those are the varieties of infinity which leap to mind, but I'm sure there are others. But we can't conflate these: e.g. the cardinal $\aleph_0$ and the extended real number $+\infty$ are simply unrelated objects.